# Nuget Package supporting multiple versions of their dependency

Tags: entity-framework, nuget, entity-framework-6

I'm looking for some experience or thoughts on the following problem.

I have a Nuget Package ([EntityFrameworkExtras 1.2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFrameworkExtras/)) thats hosted on the main Nuget Feed.

This package has a dependency on EntityFramework. **Everything was hunky dorey until EntityFramework 6 was released**.

A change in the EntityFramework code means that my package no longer works with EntityFramework 6 and onwards.

*I'm trying to consider how best to deal with this problem, i foresee two options:*

#### 1) Maintain 2 versions of the Package

So, i would have one version of the package that is compiled with EntityFramework 5.0.0 and the *.nuspec* would
dictate that it is dependant on EntityFramework [0.0.0 - 5.0.0]

I would introduce a new package called EntityFrameworkExtras (ef6). This package would be compiled in EntityFramework 6.0.0
and the *.nuspec* would dictate that it is dependant on EntityFramework [6.0.0 >= *]

#### 2) Have a new version of the current package that would support EntityFramework 6.0

so the currently version would support EntityFramework 5.0.0 and less 
and i would add a new version of the package (version 2.0.0) that would depend on EntityFramework 6.0.0 [6.0.0 >= *]

Comment: You see both of these options used. If you look at a package like Glimpse you will see the package is called `Glimpse.EF5`, `Glimpse.EF6`, etc.

Comment: I'll take that has a vote for 1) :)

Comment: Just looking through the package listings on Nuget, people seem to favour option 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went for option 1) in the end. I believe this is an easier option for the user of the packages because its clear what each of the package's dependencies are.

I also believe its easier to use the nuget commands when working with different packages, rather then attempting to be aware that different versions of one package have different dependency versions.

Also from a development perspective it cleaner and easier to develop and fix bugs on the different packages. Finally, it would make a continuous integration environment easier to implement, because each package would be consider a different project.